# How to link mailto with default email client?

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I want to know is there any way to get any machine's default email client?
In chrome when I click on a link with the `mailto` attribute, it opens with Gmail compose mail(*not with machine's default email client*).

> **But I want it to open that link with that machine's default email client.**

E.g.

```
mailto:example@xyz.com?..... // all parameters
```

Is there any extra parameter I need to pass on that link?
Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using protocol handler?

Comment: by default it does open through user's default email client. Maybe you've overwritten your browsers defaults to gmail.

Comment: @guest271314 : No, I never heard about it. Can you tell me how to use it ?

Comment: @IsuruKusumal : No, its actually showing outlook is default mail client.

Comment: See [Navigator.registerProtocolHandler()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the browser settings. You can't change it using JavaScript.

Have a look at http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-change-the-default-email-program-for-mailto-links/

Comment: Your suggestion won't help me because I know this, I can't tell user to go through all these things when they click on link and wants to open in their machine's default mail client. That I need to do something, so that mailto link will open in user's default mail client

Comment: You cannot force a user to open a certain program, the browser handles passing the mailto link to the correct mail client that the user has set.

Comment: @AlexisTyler : I am not saying it must be possible, I am asking the question, I know its not possible so asked question expecting the alternative regarding same.